# make: *** [out/target/common/docs/api-stubs-timestamp] error 45

Tags: android, sdk

When I compile Android SDK Source code，I got some problem:

```
javadoc: error - cannot find file："out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/src/android/R.java"

javadoc: error - cannot find file："out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/src/android/Manifest.java"

javadoc: error - cannot find file："out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/src/com/android/internal/R.java" 3 error    

make: *** [out/target/common/docs/api-stubs-timestamp] error 45
```

How can I get the compilation to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem when I tried to compile lollipop version with java 7. The thing was that I had 2 installed versions of java:

- open jdk java 7
- oracle java 9

For some reason not all alternatives (for java, javac, jar etc) were set to open jdk java 7.

So I fixed this by:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

I hava solved this question:

google's document say that:compile sdk should use jdk 1.5,but I has only install jdk 1.6.so I had install jdk 1.5.

than,we should copy javadoc.1.gz and javadoc from jdk 1.5 to /etc/alternatives ,Execute the following command in shell ：

$cd /etc/alternatives

$sudo rm javadoc.1.gz

$sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun/man/man1/javadoc.1.gz javadoc.1.gz

$sudo rm javadoc

$sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun/bin/javadoc javadoc

$sudo gedit~/.bashrc

add:

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun

JRE_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/jre

export ANDROID_JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME

export CLASSPATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$CLASSP ATH

export JAVA_PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${JRE_HOME}/bin

export JAVA_HOME;

export JRE_HOME;

export CLASSPATH;

HOME_BIN=~/bin/

export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_PATH}:${JRE_PATH}:${HOME_BIN};

#echo $PATH;

$ source ~/.bashr

ok!